# Error with gedit installation in centos

Tags: installation, centos, gedit

I installed gedit by:

```
sudo yum install gedit
```

OUTPUT:

(process:29842): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(gedit:29842): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

So i installed gtk:

```
sudo yum install gtk2
```

But still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a couple of things, either you don't have the right locales installed or they're not loaded. You can see what is loaded with

```
locale -a
```

You may see some "no such file or directory" errors, fix this with

```
/usr/sbin/build-locale-archive
```

If it still fails then try

```
sudo yum reinstall glibc-common
```

or

```
sudo yum install glibc-common
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply...but...locale cmd gave me a huge list (cant make out what!) ....for the last 2 cmd ...it says "command not found"....